# Как научить чат-бота отвечать на множество определённых слов одним сообщением?

Tags: python, python-3.x, вконтакте, if, бот

К примеру, чтобы он отвечал "Привет", на слова (привет, Привет, здравствуйте, Приветствую...)
Расписывать в функциях if, elif, else как то долго и не правильно по моему мнению.
Если не сложно ребят, лучше всего с примером, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: ну можно составить список слов и проверять на вхождение в этот список только. Один if.

Answer (score 1):

ну можно так:

```
hello=['привет','здравствуйте','приветствую']
inp=input()
if inp.lower() in hello:
    print('Привет!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте массив со всеми значениями, которые Вы хотите, чтобы чат-бот принимал.
Пропишите цикл for, прописывающий все значения массива в команде if